# Circuit design and frequency response of cascade PI controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, filter, transfer-function

A controller system is built with tow cascaded PI sub-controllers like shown in the circuit below:

I have design the circuit for simulation of PI controllers used in DC motor control.The first controller build around X6 OPAMP, represents PI speed controller, and the second represents PI current controller. In DC motor control, the outer speed controller generates the reference suitable current for the inner current control.

In my simulation, I have chosen:

- The current loop is built around **X5** and the speed loop is built around **X6**.
- The Bandwidth of the inner current loop is 6280 rad/sec (Faster than the outer loop).
- The Bandwidth of the outer speed loop is 314 rad/s (20 times slower than current loop).
- The Switching frequency for simulation is: 20kHz.

The circuit I showed is used for AC analysis, and my questions are:

**1. The two controllers simulated separately:**

When the two PI controllers simulated separately i.e: the reference voltages of the two OPAMPS are fixed stable DC voltage sources. (See the circuit: V2=2v for X5 unit and V18=50v for X6 unit) , The Bode plot take the standard shape of any PI controller (very high gain for small frequencies, limited by open loop gain of OPAMP. Constant gain at the corner frequency of PI ). The DC plot met my analytical expectations and shows that the two OPAMP are well biased and operates at the linear region.
[image]

[image]

**2. The reference of X5 is generated by X6 (Cascade control):**
In my second part, I want to feed the reference of the PI current controller with the ouput of the PI speed controller as in the circuit below:

[image]

Now, when I performe the AC and DC analysis of this circuit, I got the following graphs

[image]

What I have noticed is that, the frequency response of the PI current controller is affected by this connection and the perturbations goes through the non-inverting input of X5 and nulls the origin pole of the current PI controller.
The DC points of the controllers are well baised and the reference of the current controller is well generated by X6.

My questions are:

1. What would be the effect of this design on the whole stability issiue?
2. Since the DC points are stable and bounded, can this design be used for cascade control?

3.How can I avoid the distortion of the current PI frequency response and yet use the speed controller output to feed the reference input of the current controller ?

Comment: I don't understand why you did place the ac injection signal between the input and the output of the op-amp? Perhaps you've seen them, but you can check some of the compensators I offered for [download](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Divers/Compensators%20SIMPLIS.zip), I have automated the compensation values of the components to meet design criteria.

Comment: @VerbalKint, Of course there are different methods used for AC analysis of OPAMS, that I have seen used in TINA TI, LTSpice and so on. I have inspired this method from the fact that the simulator starts by calculating DC operating points, so it shorts the AC source and gets the DC operating point forced by the reference voltage at the non-inverting input. The bode plots I got from this method met the ones got from other well known methods, but with diffrent DC point. The problem here, from the AC response, we notice the absence of origine pole of the inner PI controller (Cascade configuration)

Comment: still, I don't understand how you inject and measure, sorry. To me, if I only speak about the right-side op-amp, the upper connection of \$R_{12}\$ should go a ground-referenced series connection of ac + dc: ac is the modulating signal and dc, a 100-V source or so, perfectly tuned so that X6 output doesn't rail up or down. Then the TF box is placed between X6 out and the upper connection of \$R_{12}\$.